# Why non english text doesnt gets INSERTED in the mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, mysqli

i am trying to `INSERT` the title in the mysql database field type char(255) like this

```
$text = 'Лига Справедливости Кризис двух Миров (Justice League Crisis on Two Earths)';

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO temp (title) VALUES (?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $text);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
printf("%d Row inserted.\n", mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt));
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

but when i see the inserted value in the db it shows **empty**

**why is that ?
how can i fix it ?**

---

More info

```
mysql> status
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.39, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Connection id:          457
Current database:
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.5.39 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    utf8
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
UNIX socket:            /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Uptime:                 2 days 13 hours 46 min 13 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 1419373  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 1001  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 45  Queries per second avg: 6.382
--------------
```

---

i tried

1)

```
if (!mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    die();
}
```

2)

```
$text = @iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $text);
```

Comment: How are you viewing the row in the table?

Comment: What is the `CHARSET` of the table?

Comment: What do you see if you do `SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(title) FROM temp`?

Comment: i tried that too it shows 0

Comment: i changed type to medium text thought the 255 chars are low , CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp` (
  `title` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59841/discussion-between-amb-and-barmar).

Comment: By the way, you should be using utf8mb4 nowadays. See https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Answer (score 0):

Try using `urlencode()` function in php.Use the code below

```
$text = urlencode('Лига Справедливости Кризис двух Миров (Justice League Crisis on Two Earths)');

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO temp (title) VALUES (?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $text);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
printf("%d Row inserted.\n", mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt));
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

When getting the data just use urldecode() function to decode the value

```
<?php
 $text = urlencode('Лига Справедливости Кризис двух Миров (Justice League Crisis on Two Earths)');
echo $text."<br>"; // will print the encoded text
echo urldecode($test); // Will print the decoded text
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: still 0 characters , i guess something is wrong in configuration. let me double check everything.